# systemd - how to power on USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-drive, udisks

With udisksctl I'm able to power-off device:
`udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdd`

But how can I power it back ON from commandline?

Comment: There  is no command to power on a previously powered off device.   The workaround is to rescan for the device.

Comment: @fpmurphy what exactly should one do to "rescan for the device"? (e.g. if one's /usb4/power/runtime_status is "suspended", not "active". )

Answer (score -2):

```
$ rmmod ehci_platform
$ modprobe ehci_platform
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: Hello greg. To help future readers it would be useful for you to expand your answer to explain what this does, and why it helped.